# Why use a double fuse for a relay-controlled heater?

Tags: fuses

After [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37551/different-design-in-relay-load-connections), another refrigerator "mistery" :-)
This is the schematic of a no-frost refrigerator that I had to fix because the no-frost system failed and a huge quantity of ice clogged the evaporator.

[image]

R1 and R2 are two heating elements (the no-frost heaters). Power to heaters is supplied by a relay driven from the CPU board.

Question: **why those two fuses?**

Why put two fuses, in a single case, in a position that requires disassembly of half the fridge just to test them, and almost impossible to replace?

Note that TF1 and TF2, that are described simply as "fuses" in the service manual, and not as "Thermal Fuses" as the "TF" name suggest, are both in a single un-marked sealed plastic case with just the 4 cables exiting from it, placed inside the refrigerator compartment almost in direct contact with the evaporator (as everything else: just the two cables on top of the schematic enters the compartment)

[image]

Note that in the service procedures related to no-frost failures there is an explicit statement that asks to "check continuity of TF1 and TF2". And also note that the failure was indeed one of the two fuses that opened without evident cause.

Comment: I see you're from Italy. If I remember correctly, Italian 3 pin power plugs have no protection from polarity reversal. Maybe the design has something to do with that?

Comment: @AndrejaKo True, there is no protection from polarity reversal. But those two fuses are NOT the main fuses (that are placed near the compressor, in a location easily reachable from outside. The two fuses in the schematic are inside the refrigerator, and are almost inpossible to replace .  And I've noticed just now that a single missing word ("those") altered the meaning of my question. Edit :-)

Comment: Interesting. Is there any way for you to open the plastic case and post picture of its insides?

Comment: @AndrejaKo "I'm afraid I can't do that" (cit.) :-)  To have the refrigerator work again, I've shorted the two wires of the blown "fuse" and let the other "fuse" in place. I don't think it's a good idea to also remove the other without knowing *why* there is that component in the circuit.

Comment: If they're thermal fuses it may have more to do with heat propagation than anything electrical. If there's a risk of the thing overheating in different places you'd put a thermal fuse in each of those places to protect against fire risk. I'd be very wary of bypassing them. The fact they're inside and hard to get to also suggests its over-heating and not over-current they're protecting against.

Comment: @PeterBagnall True. But, as I wrote, the two fuses are **a single component** (a 2x2x1cm plastic box). They can't detect  overheating in two different places.

Comment: @Axeman, ah, missed that rather important detail, was looking at the schematic too much!

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess.  If both sides are possibly driven from "hot" AC, then a fuse in each leg makes sense since each leg could get separately shorted to ground or neutral.

No, I haven't specifically seen this myself, and again, this is just a guess.  Keep in mind that consumer devices in particular are highly cost-optimized.  That means somebody thought about this and felt it was necessary to have two fuses, possibly for regulatory reasons.

Comment: Good guess, but they're not mains related. I've found the device description in another refrigerator service manual (of the same brand). @PeterBagnall was on the right track: it's actually a Twin Thermal Fuse. Two fuses in the same package (I wonder why!) both built to "blow" at more than 70°C. They're used as security system for failures of the control logic. Nice to read on that second service manual that "Thermal Fuses can blow by itself with no particular reason" :-(   I'll replace it with an equivalent part.